# Running rdesktop via SSH Tunnel causes ERROR: Failed to open display:

Tags: openssh, ssh-tunnel, rdesktop

I can use rdesktop fine on my Linux Mint (3.2.0-23-generic kernel) system like this :

> rdesktop IPAddress

However, I'd like to run rdesktop through my OpenSSH ssh tunnel. I using the following:

> ssh user@localhost rdesktop 123.456.789.123
>
> enter password : PasswordInputted
>
> Autoselected keyboard map en-gb
> ERROR: Failed to open display:

What am I doing wrong? ( i have read [this already](https://superuser.com/questions/509825/running-rdesktop-through-a-ssh-tunnel-in-one-command)

Comment: Add the `-X` switch to the ssh command

Comment: Yes I think this is an X error - ssh -X should work. Check this by doing a ssh user@localhost xterm

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and the error does not show but then neither does the rdesktop interface? It just shows the cursor in the terminal?